# Cannot escape url as needed

Tags: karate

I am tring to escape some values in a path.

Let's say I'm trying to obtain `https://www.google.com/https%3A%2F%2Fdomain`

I've tried the following options :

```
Scenario: escape value
    * url "https://www.google.com"
    * path "https://domain"
    When method get
    * path "https\:\/\/domain"
    When method get
    * path "https%3A%2F%2Fdomain"
    When method get
    * path "https\\:\\/\\/domain"
    When method get
```

But I obtain

1. `https://www.google.com/https://domain`
2. `https://www.google.com/https://domain`
3. `https://www.google.com/https%253A%252F%252Fdomain`

Why is `\` not working, while `%2F` is being escaped into `%252F`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encoding is the correct behavior: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

But your workaround for this un-usual URL is in Karate make it as part of the `url` itself:

```
Given url 'https://httpbin.org/https%3A%2F%2Fdomain'
When method get
Then status 200
```

Comment: But the thing is that when trying to encode / (%2F), karate  encodes the % to %25. If there is no automatic encoding of /, why is there one for %?
Your workaround using url instead of path works, but it complicates things a bit.

Comment: @Adrien no it won’t complicate things. you can build a url using string concatenation of a variable if needed. the / is expected in paths.

Comment: I know that / is expected in paths, but I don't understand why % isn't, when it is present in encoded parts of the url, and surencoding it isn't really instinctive IMO.

Comment: @Adrien ok i don’t know either ;) we just use the apache http client behind. maybe you can submit a pull request ?

Comment: If I manage to do that, I'll for sure contribute to the project :)