# How to dynamically create URL having path in between URL using Karate framework

Tags: karate

I want to create a dynamic url using karate framework. lets assume URL I want to create is :

```
https://www.mars.com/mars/profile/{profileID}/line
```

In above URL `{profileID}` is path.

Currently I have written below feature file which is able to create the url however  due using path keyword it encodes the url and add `%0A` after profile id.

```
https://www.mars.com/mars/profile/264%0A/line
```

Feature File:

```
@smoke
Scenario: Create  a line score in existing  profile
And def urlname = marsuri+ '/mars/profile/'

Given url urlname
Given path id + '/line'
```

Please let me know how can I create a URL with path in between URL without encoding it.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the `path` syntax correctly. Please read the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#path

Make this change:

```
Given path id, 'line'
```

EDIT: please also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54477346/143475

Comment: I used as suggested however ,     @smoke
 Scenario: Create  a line score in existing  profile
  And def urlname = marsuri+ '/mars/profile/'
  Given url urlname
  Given path id, 'line'

Comment: still getting below error:   com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: status code was: 404, expected: 200, response time: 13, url: https://www.mars.com/mars/profile/268%0A/line, response: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>

 at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.status(StepDefs.java:491)

Comment: @Automation_Test it is time to refer you to these instructions ! all the best ;) https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Answer (score 0):

Actually that `id` variable wherever you are getting it from is having a new line at the end of the string, something like this `"264\n"` that is why it is getting encoded to `264%0A`

If all you wanted to pass is `"264"` you have to remove the unwanted values before adding it to the `path`

```
Background:
* def removeNewLine = function(x){return x.replace("\n","")}

Scenario: Create  a line score in existing  profile
And def urlname = marsuri+ '/mars/profile/'
Given url urlname
* def id = removeNewLine(id)
Given path id + '/line'
```

If you can modify the data directly from the source where you are getting the `id` that would be great.

Comment: Great Babu Sekaran, It worked , I never realized id was carrying "\n" with it. Good Catch