# How to handle parameters in the URL using PATH in Karate DSL framework?

Tags: automated-tests, cucumber, karate

I have read the documentation on: https://github.com/intuit/karate#path

I have also read many answers on related subject on these forums, most notably: [How to dynamically create URL having path in between URL using Karate framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54855214/how-to-dynamically-create-url-having-path-in-between-url-using-karate-framework)

However, I still cannot get my head around this concept. Perhaps I am even more a newbie than a typical newbie. My problem is this:

```
The complete api: /sample/api/v1/sampleweb/{sampleweb}/webversion/{version}

    Feature:
    
        Background:
            * def baseUrl = '/sample/api/v1/'
    
        @postRandomData
        Scenario: POST API for creating data
            Given url host
            And path baseUrl
```

How in the world can I add the rest of the Url to "baseUrl" (basically the complete path listed above)? Should I throw "sampleweb/{sampleweb}/webversion/{version}" into a variable and then just do "baseUrl + variable"?

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use string concatenation. Just like normal JavaScript. Here try to spot the difference between "hard coded" strings and variables.

```
* def want = 'something'
* url baseUrl + '/anything'
* path 'you', want
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, I can possibly do something like:

`And path baseurl + '/sampleweb/{sampleweb}/webversion/{version}'`

Comment: @hungryhippos no you can't

Comment: I think I will do: 
`And path baseurl, 'sampleweb', sampleweb, 'webversion', version`

And remove the "/" from the baseUrl variable so there is no extra forward slash.

Comment: @hungryhippos I think you still haven't got it. you can't mix a URL (which starts with `http`) and the `path` keyword. anyway, just try a few combinations (or read the docs ;)

Comment: It's an API call, I misworded my request perhaps. It's not a traditional URL (starting with http). But yes, I will try combos as you suggested. Thank you so much for your assistance!

Comment: @hungryhippos what i do to have this kind of flexibility is to use smth like:
  
    var endpoint = '/sampleweb/{sampleweb}/webversion/{version}'.replace('{sampleweb}', param1).replace({version}', param2)

Answer (score 2):

@hungryhippos what i do to have this kind of flexibility is to use something like:

```
var endpoint =  '/sampleweb/{sampleweb}/webversion/{version}'
.replace('{sampleweb}', param1)
.replace({version}', param2)
```

Comment: Very interesting solution. Thank you for sharing.