# How to build a url with a dynamic url segment

Tags: testing, karate

I'm sorry to ask this question because [it's already been asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54855214/how-to-dynamically-create-url-having-path-in-between-url-using-karate-framework). However, I can't get the proposed solution to work.
Here I have the following url with a dynamically changing user id:

```
Given path '/toto/tutu', userId,'customer', 'new'
```

I'd like this url to be, for example:

```
/toto/tutu/123456/customer/new
```

But the code returns:
[print] /toto/tutu 123456 customer/new

I've also tried:

```
'/toto/tutu/' + userId + '/customer/new'
```

but that doesn't work either

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this example, it works fine:

```
* def userId = 123456
* url 'https://httpbin.org/get'
* path '/toto/tutu', userId, 'customer', 'new'    
* method get
```

The URL will be: `https://httpbin.org/get/toto/tutu/123456/customer/new`

You are missing something or maybe confused, because `print` will not process the same way as `path`.