# How can I set base API? I see double quotes getting added from the first API's response

Tags: karate

```
Given path '/api/metrics/product/ABC'
When method get
   * def id = get response
   * print id
   * def basePathProducts = '/another/api/' + id + '/param'   
  Given path basePathProducts
  When method GET
  Then status 200
```

12:59:28.447 [main] INFO com.intuit.karate.StepDefs - [print] "5ca627bf3edd851238e59c9e" Apr 16, 2019 12:59:28 PM org.glassfish.jersey.logging.LoggingInterceptor log SEVERE: 2 * Sending client request on thread main 2 > GET

http://localhost:8080/API/ANOTHER/API/%225ca627bf3edd851238e59c9e%22/PARAM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating things and you missed that the `path` syntax is designed for what you commonly need to do.

Don't `def basePathProducts` and do this, see how the `id` variable can be easily plugged into a path:

```
Given path 'another', 'api', id, 'param'
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit Thomas. The double quotes from the first response( "5ca627bf3ghut56c9e") is getting appended in the URL as %22. How do I skip that?

Comment: @Knight `* def id = get response` looks wrong, please look at the docs and examples, there are many ways to extract the data you need cleanly - unless your response is a string - then just do a replace if needed

Comment: Oops, didn't notice the "get" came here..it was one of the unsuccessful trial attempts :p. Yes, the response I'm getting is a string.

Answer (score 2):

Your post is really hard to comprehend.

Try using

```
Given url yourURLVariable + 'another/api/'+ id + '/param'
```

Refer to this for more information : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54477346/10791639

Edit :
There is a problem with your parameter.

```
* def id = "5ca627bf3edd851238e59c9e"
* print id
```

Gives :

```
13:24:19.783 [print] 5ca627bf3edd851238e59c9e
```

So your variable `id` is `"5ca627bf3edd851238e59c9e"` instead of `5ca627bf3edd851238e59c9e`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Adrien I couldn't edit the code as I posted it thru my mobile(away from my machine). The response from the first API is a string so how can I escape the double quotes getting added to the second url..I did try the "Given url " I till see the %22 getting added in the url. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Knight I edited my answer. The problem is with the value you get in response, which has the `"` inside the string

Comment: Yes Adrien, I added a JS function to remove the quotes from the string and appended in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

```
* def newresp = function(id){ return id.slice(1, -1); }
* def id = newresp(response)
```

I added these to remove the first and last characters from the response which is the double quotes in my case. Thanks for responding guys!