# Unable to specify Odata URL in Karate

Tags: odata, karate

How uri can be written for  odata call like substring,startswith. Tried with above mentioned ideas but doesn't  respond with success status .tried appending in param as well but uri doesn't seem to resolve to correct path
Query like :-》
filter=substringof('m',Title)
Trying like :-》

1. - path "host?$filter=startswith(Name,"+"'?'"+")"
2. appending in param : param $filter='startswith(Name,''+internalId+'')'

but does not get resolved in correct uri .
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To prove that Karate does the right thing, try this:

```
* url 'https://httpbin.org'
* path 'anything'
* def id = 123
* param $filter = "startswith(Name,'" + id + "')"
* request { foo: 'bar' }
* method post
```

And Karate will make this request:

```
1 > POST https://httpbin.org/anything?%24filter=startswith%28Name%2C%27123%27%29
1 > Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
1 > Content-Length: 13
1 > Host: httpbin.org
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/1.8.0_231)
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
{"foo":"bar"}
```

And you will get an actual response from the server:

```
10:13:38.445 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - response time in milliseconds: 1243
1 < 200
1 < Date: Tue, 13 Apr 2021 04:43:38 GMT
1 < Content-Type: application/json
1 < Content-Length: 589
1 < Connection: keep-alive
1 < Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
1 < Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
1 < Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
{"args":{"$filter":"startswith(Name,'123')"},"headers": ""}
```

So I leave it up to you to figure if you got the wrapping of quotes wrong or if your server is not able to handle encoded URL or path / params.